# How to replace * with ✪ ("&\#x272A;") in `money_format`?

Tags: php, string, escaping, html-entities, money-format

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
$str = money_format('%=*#4.4n',163.17852837291);
```

returns `$**163.1785` for `$str`.

I'd like to print `$✪✪163.1785`, instead.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Hi @Emma, could you use a different function instead of money_format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`money_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) can only accept a single byte fill character, so you cannot directly achieve what you want. However you can use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) after `money_format` to change the `*` into `✪`:

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
$str = money_format('%=*#4.4n',163.17852837291);
$str = str_replace('*', '✪', $str);
echo $str;
```

Output:

```
✪163.1785
```

Note there's only one `✪` as you have specified a width of 4 and you have 3 digits in the number.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/AtmFe)

Answer (score 0):

You could define a specific-function this way:

```
function m_money_format($f, $s)
{
    return str_replace("*", "&\#x272a;", money_format($f,$s));
}

setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
$str = m_money_format($f, $s);
```

So you can call the function whenever you need it, in every part of you code